# Show only part of a list and toggle parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list with 16 products, but I want to show only 8 at a time, with a button to switch through the views.

I have this fiddle to show you..https://jsfiddle.net/5cLvq6bm/2/ 

Everything works fine if in css I have this :

```css
ul#carter li:nth-of-type(1n+9) {
  display: none;
}
```

But stops working if I add `!important` :

```css
ul#carter li:nth-of-type(1n+9) {
  display: none!important;
}
```

If i don't use `!important`, `display:none` doesn't affect my list...

Any suggestions?

Comment: @KittMedia , Yes, i've tried, but it doesn't works, to understand the correct working of this fiddle, try to delete !important in the Css part....If you delete !important work as expected but in my site i have to keep !important...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you are complicating stuff. Well, here's a simple solution:

```js
$("li.product:gt(8)").hide();
$(".button").click(function() {
  if ($("li.product").not(":visible").length > 0) {
    $("li.product").toggle("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.button {
  background-color: #ed241a;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: open sans;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<ul id="carter" class="products">
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li class='product'><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
</ul>
<br>
<a href="#" class="button">Switch View</a>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution, but where i have to implement it : http://www.j-e.com there is a real mess with css, so i'added your code but it only shows the first 8, because there is a display:inline!important on the li...@Praveen Kumar

Comment: @APPRAILY Change the `:gt(8)` to whatever value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `ul {
  display: inline !important;
}`

as you need !important again to override previous !important..

Also check out this article of examples to use instead of 'important': https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/